# How to start the Publisher on a specific queue in Swift Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I know how to subscribe on a specific queue using `.subscribe(on: ...)`, but what if the publisher itself needs to work on a specific queue. Here's a simple example to demonstrate:

```
class ViewModel {
    
    @Published var count: Int = 0

    func doSomething2() { // <-- may be executed from any queue
        
        guard Thread.isMainThread else { // <-- moving to main queue. Can this be improved?
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.doSomething2()
            }
            return
        }
        
        Just(count) // <-- must access `count` on main queue
            .map { value in
                count = max(0, value - 1)
                return count
            }
            .first { value in
                value > 0
            }
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
            .sink { _ in
                print("Running a long operation 2")
                self.doSomething2()
            }
    }
}

// This usage in the view has no meaning for the question, it's just to make example executable
struct MyView: View {
    
    var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Try me") {
                viewModel.count = 3
                viewModel.doSomething2()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So *in this example* is it possible to get rid of `guard Thread.isMainThread...` and instead somehow indicate the publisher to do its work on main queue?

More generically I want to know if I can tell any publisher to do its work on a specific queue declaratively, similar to `.subscribe(on: ...)` for subscriber? Or does it mean implementing a custom publisher every time I need something like this?

Comment: Add `@MainActor` to the `doSomething2` definition, which will enforce calling it from the main actor.

Comment: You can use `receive(on:)` to indicate that the pipeline should switch to a certain queue. But that doesn't solve the problem of the global `count`. If you're in a situation where `count` can be accessed from different threads, you're already in deep do-doo; you need, instead, to have an accessor method for `count` that guarantees that access with always be on the main thread. Note that this has nothing to do with Combine! The fact that you are saying `Just()` here is irrelevant; you could be saying `count` in any context whatever.

Comment: Or of course you could just say `DispatchQueue.main.async` some more. But at this point I'm liking the idea of your `may be executed from any queue` less and less. That's a Bad Smell from the get-go. The very idea of checking `isMainThread` like that is kind of horrifying. I would recommend getting off of this way of working entirely and switching to pure `async/await`, which will keep you consistent and honest (and do all the thinking for you).

Comment: I guess I just came up with a silly example, that doesn't really demonstrate the issue. The problem is not a main queue specifically - it could be any queue, custom for example, just wanted to understand if I could tell Publisher which queue to work on....

Comment: Yes, depending what "work on" means, you use `receive(on)` and/or `subscribe(on)`.

Answer (score -1):

If the question is how to ensure that `count` is accessed on (say) the main thread in the phrase `Just(count)`, then that has nothing whatever to do with publishers, Combine, or anything else; it's simply entirely up to you to make sure that that line runs on (say) the main thread, in whatever usual way you know to make sure of that (use an accessor that puts you on (say) the main thread, put this code inside of (say) `DispatchQueue.main.async`, whatever).

If the question is how to specify what thread the *rest* of the pipeline runs on, that is what `subscribe(on:)` and `receive(on:)` are for, and it seems you know about those already too: they specify the thread to be used for upstream and downstream messages within the pipeline, respectively. For example if what you want to is make sure that the publisher *publishes* on a particular thread / queue, then put `receive(on:)` right after the publisher.